# Is the inequality always true: $\dim_R (U_1 + U_2 + U_3)\leq \dim_RU_1+\dim_RU_2+\dim_RU_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

If V is the linear space over the field R of real numbers, and $U_1, U_2, U_3$ are subspaces of this space. Is the inequality always true: $\dim_R (U_1 + U_2 + U_3)\leq \dim_RU_1+\dim_RU_2+\dim_RU_3$

I tried to base my answer on what I know to be true:
If $U_1, U_2, U_3$ are finite dimensional subspaces of a vector space $V$ , then
$$\dim_R(U_1 + U_2 + U_3) = \dim_R(U_1) + \dim_R(U_2) + \dim_R(U_3)\\− \dim_R(U_1 ∩ U_2) − \dim_R(U_1 ∩ U_3) − \dim_R(U_2 ∩ U_3)$$.
So my thinking is that if we take away the intersection subtraction the right side of the equation will always be greater or equal to the left side. Therefore the inequality is always right. Am I correct? Is that how you're supposed to do this?

Comment: I think there should be an extra term $+\dim(U_1\cap U_2\cap U_3)$ in the equation, but the inequality still holds because that extra term is $\le\dim(U_i\cap U_j)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{B}_1,\mathfrak{B}_2,\mathfrak{B}_3$ are basisses of $U_1,U_2,U_3$ respectively, then $\mathfrak{B}_1\cup\mathfrak{B}_2\cup\mathfrak{B}_3$ spans the vector space (but might not be linearly independant). Therefore $\text{dim}(U_1+ U_2+U_3)\leq\text{dim}(U_1)+\text{dim}(U_2)+\text{dim}(U_3)$, since the dimension is the cardinality of a basis.

Edit: I forgot to answer your question, the answer is yes.